# Sprite Kit: Can't stop two objects from colliding

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, collision

I've got a player category, enemy category, and a wall category. I want my enemy category to be able to move through my wall category and I want my player category to stop when hitting a wall. I've got my player stopping at the wall but I'm not able to stop my enemy from colliding with my wall as well. I'm not sure why... Here is my code:

```
 static const int playerCategory =3;
 static const int wallCategory = 2;
 static const int enemyCategory = 1;
```

Enemy Code:

```
 self.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
 self.physicsBody.restitution = 0.2;
 self.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
 self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory;
 self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =  playerCategory;
 self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask =  playerCategory;
```

Wall Code:

```
 wallRight.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
 wallRight.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
 wallRight.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = wallCategory;
 wallRight.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =  playerCategory;
 wallRight.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask =  playerCategory;
```

Player Code:

```
self.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
self.physicsBody.restitution = 0.2;
self.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = wallCategory | enemyCategory;
self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = wallCategory | enemyCategory;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: these are bitmasks, you can't use arbitrary numbers 1,2,3,4,5 - you must use 1,2,4,8,16 and so on

Comment: Ah, wow. Thanks! I'm very new at this as you can probably tell. Simply changed the 3 to a 4 and that fixed it.